# Open a Remote Session from C# Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm creating a small Windows Form app so I can click on my servers and remote into them. I have setup a button and have the following code for when they click on it.

```
Process.myProcess = new Process();
Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:192.168.0.110 /f");
```

However, when I press F5, Visual Studio presents me with these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlAlk.jpg).

I'm not entirely sure how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Process` is located in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.
Add `using System.Diagnostics` before your code or just use direct class name:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:192.168.0.110 /f")
```

Comment: When I do this, I get `System.Diagnostics.Process does not contain a definition for myProcess`

Comment: Use `myProcess.Start()`.

Comment: That seems to fix it but I'm getting this `Error 1 Member 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead 
`.

Comment: @DuncanMcClean please delete these two lines and add only `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:192.168.0.110 /f")`

Comment: Really chuffed! Thanks for helping me getting it sorted. @opewix